# SpamAssassin not rewriting Subject line

Tags: linux, url-rewriting, postfix-mta, spamassassin

I can't seem get Spam Assassin to rewrite the subject lines with ***SPAM***.
This is on a Debian 7 box using Postfix, Dovecot, MySQL, and spamass-milter
Here is the relevent configuration data from the config files:

/etc/spamassassin/local.cf

```
rewrite_header Subject *****SPAM***** (_SCORE_)
report_safe 0
required_score 5.0
use_bayes 1
bayes_auto_learn 1
```

/etc/postfix/main.cf

```
smtpd_milters = unix:/clamav/clamav-milter.ctl, unix:/spamass/spamass.sock
```

/etc/defaults/spamass-milter

```
OPTIONS="-u spamass-milter -i 127.0.0.1"
OPTIONS="-r -1"
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. The `rewrite_header` won't happen unless the email's score is more than `required_score`. Apparently the test emails I was using was only asdding up to 2.4 (I needed at least 5.0 to trigger the `rewrite_header`.

As a test, I modifed the required score to 2.0 and sent my test email through again. This time, it was rewritten!